# get real values from solve function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function in Matlab and want to find it's points in which value of F is 0.5 (more than one point) I wrote my code as bellow : (function defined in '')

```
 result=solve('(1/(1+ ((x-5)/2)^(2*4)))=0.5');
```

but this return both real and complex x in which value of function is 0.5, I need just real numbers. how can I get real results from solve function in Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found in the documentation of [solve](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/solve.html):

```
result = solve('(1/(1+ ((x-5)/2)^(2*4)))=0.5', 'Real', true)
```

By the way, you could also get the desired real valued subset of the results by considering `result(1:2)`. Changing the array of sym class values to an array of double values can be done with `double(result)`, after which you can use `isreal` to obtain the real solutions as well.